# Is there a way to check if too many VC are stacked

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, performance, uiviewcontroller

I wonder if there is a way to check if I have too many views stacked in my app.

My app design is:

Navigation controller -> table view (table view works like root VC)

From the table view I can open the menu VC as a modal segue, and form there I can open the login VC as a modal segue, if I log in I end up on the account page like:

**Navigation controller -> table view -> menu -> login -> account page**

From the account page I can go deeper:

**Navigation controller -> table view -> menu -> login -> account page -> list settings page -> edit settings page**

Now I have 7 VC's stacked if I count the navigation controller, even though two of them are displayed as modal VC's.

My app does not crash but is this a good way to do it? If I understand it right apps now have to share CPU when running split screen on ipad, so I am not sure if this way is eating too much memory.

Or should I simply make the account VC become the new root VC and reset the stack? And when going back to the table view make that one the new root VC again.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

View Controllers are light weight objects. If your concern is memory you should react to memory warnings. E.g. in the viewcontrollers' `didReceiveMemoryWarning` method. You could release any cached images, remove views if the VC is not visible. Releasing cached objects and images is not always desirable in `viewDidDisappear` as the user might come back to the screen and you want to avoid reloading everything if there are no memory issues. `didReceiveMemoryWarning` is the correct place to help the system in freeing memory without sacrificing user experience.

You can of course check how many view controllers are on a navigation controllers stack by checking the `UINavigationController`'s property `viewControllers.count`.

Resetting the stack to always only have one root viewcontroller is nice but usually quite complex. It is also not really possible inside a navigation controller.

You should use Instruments to check your memory consumption and to verify that you correctly react to memory warnings. Memory warnings can be manually triggered in the simulator.

Comment: Thanks for your answer got some more stuff to read on about :)

Answer (score 2):

So when views are stacked on a navigation controller, they are not fully de-allocated from memory, even when they are offscreen. There isn't a strict maximum number of stacked views but you should be smart about it.

If you are concerned about RAM usage then be sure to utilise `viewWillAppear` and `viewWillDisappear` to their full potential, performing cleanup operations such as nulling off gesture recognisers and observers, and stopping any listeners that may be running on a background thread. This will reduce the amount of memory your views are using when offscreen; and is good coding practice anyway.

Hope this helps somewhat.

EDIT: Felix also raises a good point about memory warnings, if iOS is concerned about the memory usage of your app it will issue a memory warning which you can react to in the way felix explains.